# What is the difference between rails console and bundle console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can anyone explain me or give me a resource where I can learn the differences between rails console and bundle console? Is there way to load all the gems automatically in irb instead of require gem?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is a good explanation: [What's the Difference Between `irb`, `bundle exec irb`, `bundle console`, and `rails console`?](http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2014/11/17/what-are-the-differences-between-irb/?utm_source=Weissblog%20Subscribers&utm_campaign=dc22dc3715-What_are_the_differences_between_irb_11_17_2014&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_2494b7d197-dc22dc3715-122710969)

> **irb** is the basic Ruby console. It ignores your Gemfile, and only core
>   Ruby classes are accessible without require-ing them. It can’t easily
>   load gems that Bundler installs outside of RubyGems’ load path.
>
> **bundle exec irb** is like irb, if you also required bundler/setup. You
>   can only easily require gems that are in your Gemfile.lock, but you
>   can load those gems no matter where Bundler put them.
>
> **bundle console** is like bundle exec irb, if you also called
>   Bundler.require. All of the gems in your Gemfile, except the ones
>   marked require: false, can be used without requiring them. It’s really
>   convenient when you’re writing your own gems, or working on non-Rails
>   code.
>
> **rails console** is like running bundle console inside a Rails app, if
>   you also required config/environment.rb. You can play with your entire
>   Rails app, autoloads and database connections work, and everything’s
>   hooked up the way you’d expect. If you’re working in a Rails app, this
>   is the most helpful kind of console.

Answer (score 8):

The answer from Aleksandr is great.

I just wanted to add there is also the option for running

> bundle exec rails console

which combines everything from *rails console* and *bundle exec irb* answer from Aleksandr's answer.